# Vim run a row as Command

Tags: vim, command

I'm trying to run a command from within vim, and capture the resulting Statuscode.

My Command:

```
.!curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://rtl.de
```

To get the Statuscode I unsuccessfully tried:

```
:execute getline(".")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the `%`, otherwise vim will expand it as filepath.

```
.!curl -s -o /dev/null -w "\%{http_code}" http://rtl.de
```

should go.

If you don't like to change the command, you can call:

```
:execute escape(getline("."),'%')
```